# How do I decode strings-like objects to extract subject?

Tags: python, smtplib, imaplib

I am trying to fetch emails so that I can save them in a spreadsheet. So far, it works without getting the status of the message, but when I try to fetch the status ('Delivered', for example) I get the following error:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

when the exception is raised and I print out the result in subject_2 I get a string-like object, for example: "P45 employee"

How to deal with this?

MY GOAL IS TO EXTRACT THE MAIL STATUS: DELIVERED, READ, RELAYED

```
imap.select('[Gmail]/Enviados')
typ, data = imap.search(None, 'ALL')


to=[]
subject=[]
sent_date=[]
delivered_mails=[]
for num in data[0].split():
  
    typ, data = imap.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    #print('Message %s\n%s\n' % (num, data[0][1]))
    msg=email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
    to.append(msg['To'])
    subject.append(msg['Subject'])
    sent_date.append(msg['Date'])

    try:

      subject_2, encoding=decode_header(msg['Subject'])[0]
      if isinstance(subject_2, bytes):
                  subject_2=subject_2.decode(encoding)
      if "Delivered" in subject_2:
        delivered_mails.append(subject_2)

    except:
      subject_2, encoding=decode_header(msg['Subject'])[0]
      if isinstance(subject_2, string):
                  subject_2=subject_2.decode(encoding)
      if "Delivered" in subject_2:
        delivered_mails.append(subject_2)
```

Fulltrace of error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-39903a4919b9> in <module>()
     19 
---> 20       subject_2, encoding=decode_header(msg['Subject'])[0]
     21       if isinstance(subject_2, bytes):

2 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/email/header.py in decode_header(header)
     79     # If no encoding, just return the header with no charset.
---> 80     if not ecre.search(header):
     81         return [(header, None)]

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-39903a4919b9> in <module>()
     25 
     26     except:
---> 27       subject_2, encoding=decode_header(msg['Subject'])[0]
     28       if isinstance(subject_2, string):
     29                   subject_2=subject_2.decode(encoding)

/usr/lib/python3.7/email/header.py in decode_header(header)
     78                     for string, charset in header._chunks]
     79     # If no encoding, just return the header with no charset.
---> 80     if not ecre.search(header):
     81         return [(header, None)]
     82     # First step is to parse all the encoded parts into triplets of the form

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: Can you add a stacktrace as well ?

Comment: Sure, just added!

Comment: Did you print what is coming in `msg['Subject']` ?

Comment: prints None.. in this case, any idea of how to extract the status of the message in imaplib?

Comment: Are you sure the mail have a subject ?